# How do I cut already installed vinyl planks that are partially under wall?

Tags: concrete, mold, vinyl-flooring, saw

I had my office enclosed by having a contractor add wall and sliding doors.

I need to replace my flooring due to mold issue, and along the length of the new office wall, there are planks about 1/2 way under the wall and half out.

Planks are 12 mm thick. I tried oscillating saw and burned out blade. Tried again and I just can't seem to get thru last 2 feet or so. Jigsaw hits concrete as I can only prop up one side since other side is wall to compensate for blade length. A circular saw won't get close enough to the wall.

Comment: Are your planks attached to the floor? A photo would be helpful. If not attached, have you tried scoring with a utility knife, then prying up end of plank to snap it off?

Comment: I did try scoring, it wouldn't cut through the plank at all. Not sure why. Thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a grinder.  And you can purchase any type of blade for it you can think off.
Here is the picture of a grinder and one sample blade that will cut the wood and anything that gets in its way.
The blade on the grinder cuts metal and the other blade cuts wood and any nails that gets in the way too.
You don't have to cut the board all the way down to the concrete. Leave 1/8" of the board behind and you simply left up the board and the entire board will snap off.

If this helps let me know.
Grinder is much cheaper than the flush cut saw you see everything in pictures.

Take care.

[image: Grinder]
[image: grinder blade]
[image: Flush cut]
[image: flush cut 2]

Comment: Thank you! I ended up finishing with the oscillating tool. Your idea would have been much easier. I should have posted this before I began!